# Include a whole CSS file, but only apply this whole file to some certain divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote some css before, that is for a form. Now I am designing a new website and I need to use the css I wrote before, but if I link the older CSS file to the page, it will overwrite some css rules for current website. Is there a way to apply the css only to some part of the html, say, a div?

**I want to make this more clear. The older CSS file has 1100 lines, and it's being compressed, what I really need is only few lines in it, and I don't want to grab them from it, it will take times and I can not be sure I grab all I need, so I want to link the whole css file to the page, and apply the older file, only the some certain div**

Comment: Yes if the div has a class or id.

Comment: Just use a class or id

Comment: You could add a class or id attribute to that `div` element and prepend that id/class selector before your current selectors, as `.myClass form { }`

Comment: This is very basic CSS - could you not read the first page of the tutorial

Comment: I want to make this more clear. the older css I want to use is hidden in a .css file, and it's being compressed, it will take a lot efforts to grab what I really need. I just want to link the older css file, and use some special rules, not all of them in the css file, and then apply the css file to the certain div

Comment: I want to make this more clear. The older CSS file has 1100 lines, and it's being compressed, what I really need is only few lines in it, and I don't want to grab them from it, it will take times, so I want to link the whole css file to the page, and apply the older file, only the some certain div

Comment: Maybe using this to uncompress http://cssunpacker.com/ and then going along?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the div has a classs e.g.:

```
<div class="some-name">Some text</div>
```

The CSS would be:

```
.some-name
{
     css stlyes go here
}
```

If the div has an id e.g.:

```
<div id="some-name">Some text</div>
```

The CSS would be:

```
#some-name
{
     css stlyes go here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML you just use `id's` and `classes`

Here's an `ID`

HTML:

```
<div id="intro">
<p> Hi </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#intro {
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Here's a `class`:

HTML

```
<div class="hi">
 <p> Hi </p>
 </div
```

CSS:

```
.hi { 
 color:#009DFF;
}
```

A `CLASS` should be used for many elements that you want the same styling for, say images. You define a `CLASS` with a `.`.

An `ID` should only be used for one unique element, say sign in form. An `ID` is defined with a `#`.

Answer (score 0):

CSS provide the `class` and `id` to let you define the tag.
For example,

**HTML file:**

```
<div class = "test">
    Test
</div>
<div id = "test2">
    Test2
</div>
```

**CSS file:**

```
.test{
    background-color:red;
}
#test2{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Demo: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aq5VV/)

There are some reference data: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp